# Javascript isn't copying into the clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, copy, alert, clipboard

i have a question, i have a code, which is partially working.

```js
let dataName = "String"
navigator.clipboard
        .writeText(dataName) //push string into clipboard
        .then(() => {
          alert(dataName + "successfully copied");
          closeWindow()
          })
      .catch(() => {
        alert("something went wrong");
          });
```

In this version, the code is pushing dataName into the clipboard and gives an alert, after that it closes it.
If i delete the alert, it closes the window, without copying it into the clipboard, not going into the catch ("something went wrong").
I do not want to have the alert, it should just push the string into the clipboard and closes it.
Note:
Code is embedded into a HTML, which is empty, except of the script.
Code is partially from:
[How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: By the way: Code in the sense of a program's source code (not some numerical code, etc.) is an uncountable noun like milk. You don't have _a_ code, you just have code, or a piece of code, or some code. Getting this right will make you instantly sound more professional.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

If you add a parameter to the catch and log what you receive you will get following error `DOMException: Document is not focused`. So the user needs to have the document focused for this to work, i.e. try running `navigator.clipboard.writeText("text")`in the console. Below code should work, but stackoverflow is preventing this to work and gives a error

DOMException: The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document. See [error link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes) for more details.

```js
const copy = () => {
navigator.clipboard
  .writeText("some text") //push string into clipboard
  .then((e) => {
    alert(e + "successfully copied");
    closeWindow()
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e)
  });
}
```

```html
<button onClick="copy()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: But the OP said the `catch` is not even entered...

Comment: this is noteven working

Comment: @David that's why it's important to read the whole post